# Replace Mail Merge with syncfusion on html string data

Tags: .net-core, syncfusion

I 'm tried to replace mail merge on word template with my data using syncfusion library. Is it possible to using html format (**it is a bold text**) and text format applied on my document based on mail merge key?

I am expect the format of html string applied on my document template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to perform Mail merge with the formatted HTML string which can be achieved with the help of MergeField event and InsertXHTML API. Please find the example project from below and let us know if it helps.
http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/DocIO_CoreApp1705852960

To know more about mail merge and its events, kindly refer the following documentation link
https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/docio/working-with-mailmerge#event-support-for-mail-merge

Note: I work for Syncfusion

Regards,

Dilli babu.

Comment: thanks for your answer, at the end I am using `MailMerge_MergeField`, so I remove data if using html tag, and then replace it manually using InsertXHTML,

Comment: Hi Dilli, Is there any way to get Line breaks working? I've debugged the code, and it does seem to add some breaks in, but the content is still showing all on one line :(